# Querying sqlite table with linq returns a list with empty items

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have table in a sqlite database in a Xamarin Forms app with about 12000 items stored in it. When I try to return only one column with the following query, I got a list with all 12000 values but the entries of the list are null.

Code for the class:

```
public class BaseModel
{
        private int? _PrimaryKey;
        private string _Code;
        private string _Name;

        [PrimaryKey, Required, NotNull]
        public int? PrimaryKey { get { return _PrimaryKey; } set { _PrimaryKey = value; } }

        public string Code { get { return _Code; } set { _Code = value; } }

        public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }
}
```

I to query the table with the following line:

```
internal T GetInsertItem<T>() where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    T item = new T();
    //...
    List<int?> items = new List<int?>(_Conn.Table<T>().Select(ac => ac.PrimaryKey));
    //...
    return item;
}
```

So the result is not what i expected. I got the full list with 12000 items but every item is NULL. Why?

[Image from the debugging ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwJ3z.png)

If I use another query like the following one, it works as I expected.

```
List<T> items = new List<T>(_Conn.Table<T>().Where<T>(ac => ac.PrimaryKey > 1000));
```

Comment: Is there a column in the database called `PrimaryKey`? How many records are in the table? How many of them have a NULL `PrimaryKey`?

Comment: Just a few comments: It is weird that you define the `PrimaryKey` property as `Nullable<int>` but also decorate it with the `NotNull` or `PrimaryKey` attribute (primary key is by design not nullable). Also, instead of calling the `List new operator`, you can call the `ToList()` methods. What is the API you are using producing this code: `_Conn.Table<T>()` ?

Comment: @mjwills in the table are about 12000 rows, the field exists in the table and no row has a null value for the primarykey

Comment: @fharreau in deed it is weired but not the thing i have to decide. For the database connection i use [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) `SQLiteConnection _Conn = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().DbConnection();`

Comment: I am not familiar with this library (never used it ^^), but that looks like a bug. I mean your code looks good regarding to your goals and the LinQ conventions (but may be their select implementation does not follow the LinQ convention). You can try to replace your nuget reference by the code itself (hosted in one class, so easily replacable) and try to debug their API. If you actually find a bug you could then submit your correction as a new pull request. Or you can simply submit a bug into their github bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is an error in the implementation of select in SQLite-net, so calling `_Conn.Table<T>().ToList()` and then the select `.Select(...)` helps.
[sqlite-net issues](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/497)